# locate command does not retrive files

Tags: locate

When I use locate command with my personal account, it does not find anything, not even obvious old files. Using the same command with root privileges does find files. Using the same command when I am logged into my personal account via ssh works as well.  Running updatedb does not solve the problem. Looking at the etc/updatedb.conf I did not see any paths that should not be there. I am using the ubuntu 18.04 gnome-terminal. What could be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I think it's because all folders in the file's hierarchy must have appropriate read permissions set for the personal account. Although that doesn't necessarily explain that you can ssh into your personal account unless you ssh with sudo privileges.

Comment: What happens, when you run the following commands: `locate /etc/fstab` and `locate /boot/grub/grub.cfg` Have you tampered with the configuration of locate, or is it the default (the standard for Ubuntu)?

Comment: `locate /etc/fstab`  and `locate /boot/grub/grub.cfg` give no results. I did not tamper with the configuration.

Comment: As far as I can see I have read permissions to all the folders. I get `drwxr-xr-x` or `drwxrwxr-x` when I list my folders.

Comment: Something is wrong with your locate system. Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Is it installed directly or upgraded from a previous version? Have you tried to purge and then re-install the program package `mlocate`, which contains the program, that is used (at least for me in 18.04.x LTS).

Comment: I am running 18.04 LTS that was installed from a disk. I have tried to purge and reinstall but to no avail.

Comment: And if you run 'sudo updatedb`, what is the ouptput?  When it works correctly, there should be no output, new file should get available to locate.

Comment: I am thinking that maybe you have installed some program, that is disturbing locate. Can you think of such a program that you have installed?

Comment: running `sudo updatedb` have no output.

Comment: Let us hope that someone else can chip in and add some new ideas, that you can try.